# Where does the name Schneewittchen come from?

Tags: etymology

In German, Snow White is not called Schneeweißchen.  That name is for [another fairy tale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow-White_and_Rose-Red) character (written Snow-White in English).  Instead she is called Schneewittchen.  I also know that the Dutch word for white is wit.  I would like to know where the name Schneewittchen comes from.

Answer (score 11):

Das deutsche Wort »weiß» (übrigens auch »Weizen«), das englische »white« und das schwedische »vit« haben denselben Ursprung. Es ist das altgermanische Wort »wiz«, das sich althochdeutsch in »wiz« und »witt« aufspaltete.

»Witt« ist also ein altes Wort für »weiß«. Mit dem vorangestellten »snee« oder »schnee« in »snewitt« bzw. »schneewitt« bedeutet das Wort: »So weiß wie Schnee«.

Wollte man einem Mädchen mit schneeweißer Haut und sehr hellen Haaren einen allegorischen Namen geben, dann waren »Schneewittchen«, und später, als aus »witt« »weiß« geworden war, »Schneeweißchen« eine Wahl, die auf der Hand lag.

Aber die beiden schneeweißen Mädchen sind zwei unterschiedliche Figuren aus zwei unterschiedlichen Märchen, die beide von den Gebrüdern Grimm sind:

---

**Schneewittchen** (Schneewittchen und die sieben Zwerge):

> Schneewittchen wohnt seit ihrem siebenten Lebensjahr bei den sieben Zwergen hinter den sieben Bergen, ist die Schönste im ganzen Land, stirbt nachdem sie in einen vergifteten Apfel gebissen hat, und wird dann durch den Kuss eines Prinzen wiederbelebt.

---

**Schneeweißchen** (Schneeweißchen und Rosenrot)

> Schneeweißchen hat eine Schwester namens Rosenrot. Beide Kinder werden von einem Schutzengel bewacht, so dass sie sogar in einem Wald an einem steilen Abhang ruhig schlafen können, ohne einer Gefahr ausgesetzt zu sein. Sie spielen einen ganzen Winter lang jeden Abend mit einem Bären, der im Frühjahr fortgeht. Später erschlägt der Bär einen zornigen Zwerg, der die Mädchen bedroht. Da verwandelt sich der Bär in einen Prinzen, der Schneeweißchen heiratet. Rosenrot heiratet dessen Bruder.

Answer (score 8):

Aus [Wikipedia](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schneewittchen):

> in der Erstausgabe von 1812 war noch die Übersetzung ins Hdt.
>   **Schneeweißchen** angegeben (ndt.: Snee „Schnee“, witt „weiß“), was dann
>   wohl wegen der Gleichheit zu **Schneeweißchen und Rosenrot** weggelassen
>   wurde. Landläufig hat sich als Titel „**Schneewittchen**“ durchgesetzt.

Comment: So in case that this did not become clear: The name shows an influence from [Low German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_German).

Comment: Although just a quote, this is the correct answer. Everybody knows what "Wittchen" means. The quote explains why we  call Snow White "Schneewittchen" and not "Schneeweißchen"

Answer (score 7):

In the 1812 1st edition of the KHM, the title of No. 53 is: "Sneewittchen (Schneeweißchen)" Both names are used.

Sneewittchen is Low German, Schneeweißchen is High German.

In later editons, the High German name is deleted and only the Low German name is kept.

The Grimms address it in the Anhang (appendix) to the text: "*Dies Märchen gehört zu den bekanntesten, doch wird in Gegenden, wo bestimmt hochdeutsch herrscht, der plattdeutsche Namen beibehalten, oder auch verdorben in Schliwitchen.*" My translation of this from my 2014 translation of the 1812 Vol I text is: "*This Märchen belongs to the most well known, still in areas where High German reigns, the Low German name is kept, or even spoiled into Schliwitchen.*"

Actually, we should be careful here. "*Schneeweißchen*" is a different name/character. It is from the 1837 KHM 161 "*Schneeweißchen und Rosenroth.*" "

There is no character named "*Schneewittchen*" (note the spelling) in the original German texts.

The word "*Schneewittchen*" looks to be a combination of the *High* German (Schnee) and the *Low* German (witt) plus the *Middle* German diminutive ending (chen).

Answer (score 3):

Sneewittchen in Low (Northern) German; Schneeweißchen is High (Southern) German; Schneewittchen is a cross between the two.

Comment: That is very interesting, but does not quite explain how the two came to be used concurrently, though Alex's answer mostly covers that.